# Extract from JSON PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have three columns:

- id,
- state,
- curr_status

The curr_status column has data that’s formatted like this:

```
[{"id": 123, "created_at": "2017-07-17T19:49:19.125865", "status": "student"}]
```

I want to SELECT id, state, and extract the status for each row into a new column so it says student. New to working with JSON, how would I write the code to do that?

Comment: Why is that status information an array? And why does it repeat the id from the table? What do you want to see if the array contains more than one element with and they have different values for `"status"`?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what should happen if the array contains more than one element.

But to get the value for the first array element, you can use the `->` operator to get the first array element, then use the `->>` operator to get

```
select id, state, 
       curr_status -> 0 ->> 'status' as status
from the_table;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Your suggestion worked exactly as I needed but just wanted some help to clarify my understanding. What does it mean by an array containing more than one element? What is the significance of the 0?

Comment: @ayee007: `0` is the first element of the array. In theory your JSON column could also contain something like this: `[{"id": 123, "created_at": "2017-07-17T19:49:19.125865", "status": "student"}, {"id": 567, "created_at": "2019-01-02T18:19:20.125865", "status": "professor"}]`

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using [`json_array_elements`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html) function which firstly will split the elements of the array and then filter :

```
select id , state, js ->> 'status' as st_special
  from tab, --> your table with columns id, state, curr_status(of type json)
       jsonb_array_elements(curr_status) as js
 where js ->> 'status' = 'student';
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=32ad580f4c2d1b29b8b23d4230e1958b)</kbd>